# SOLR choose index at search

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I posted this in the Nabble group also, but figured may get some advice here.

is there a way to get SOLR to search whatever index i tell it to during search time without using multiple cores?

i dont build my indexes with SOLR, i build them with my own java class, but i do use SOLR to search them later.  It would be nice to tell Solr during search time which index to access.
I have combined them as well, and this works but there are a few issues in my particular case, that make it easier to solve with sending the index name/path at search.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think you can really do what you are looking for here.  Part of the simplicity of Solr comes from have the core (and therefore index) in the URL.  What you could do is hack how Solr works to add another parameter to the url and then when Solr goes to do a search use that to determine which index it uses.  I think you might end up throwing out all the auto warming of caches etc though.

Out of curiosity, why do you NOT want to use multiple cores?  Is it that you expect to have thousands and thousands, or that each index is incredibly transient?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Lucid Works' Enterprise Solr release.

http://www.lucidimagination.com/products/lucidworks-search-platform/enterprise

They implement Collections in a way that is similar to your use case.